# How to obtain specific modifier properties information through bpy.types?

Tags: python, blender, modifier

for example I got:

```
bpy.types.Modifier.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items[12]
```

(boolean modifier)

The Boolean modifier has a property called "object" for the actual bool mesh.
How can I quickly check if it actually got the "object" property available (through bpy.types) ?

I want to filter modifiers by their properties something like:

```
[modifier.identifier for modifier in bpy.types.Modifier.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items if modifier.object != NULL]
```

obviously this wont work, just added it for giving you a better idea of what Im trying todo.

Comment: In what context do you intend to use this. Are you checking a modifier applied to a specific object?  Because checking the object property just for the type doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another forum I was made aware of the python function `dir()` which lists all properties of an entity.

So:

```
    for mods in orig_active.modifiers:
        for properties in dir(mods):
            if "__" not in properties:
                props=eval("type(mods."+str(properties)+")")
                if "Object" in str(props):
                    print(mods.name + "modifier got a property called 'object'.")
```

A bit clunky but it works.

Answer (score 1):

[`bpy.types`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.html) contains the class definitions. [`bpy.data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.data.html) contains the instances used to define objects in your blender scene. [`bpy.context`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html) can provide easy access to several points of interest instead of using `bpy.data` directly, such as the active scene and object as well as lists of selected and visible objects.

As a class definition, `bpy.types` can only tell you what properties each type can contain, which may be after modifications. For example, an addon can use [`bpy.props`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html) to add properties to an existing data type, this is done on the class definition within `bpy.types`.

Each subclass of [`bpy.types.Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Modifier.html#bpy.types.Modifier) has its own properties, the [`BooleanModifier`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BooleanModifier.html) has an object property, this is the second object that will interact with the mesh of the modifiers parent mesh.

To access data on a specific instance of an item, you need to find the relevant data in `bpy.data`, or `bpy.context`.

For example, if a Cube had a boolean modifer that unions its mesh with a Sphere mesh, you could get the following in the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/python_console.html).

```
>>> bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['Boolean'].object
bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
>>> bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['Boolean'].operation
'UNION'
```

Comment: Thanks sambler!
"bpy.types can only tell you what properties each type can contain"
Thats exaclty what I wanted to know: What it can contain!